# I need to change font color. If passed = green and Failed = red but it's in the table(Loop Statement) so I don't know

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement

```
var x = 65;

do {
  if (x >= 75) {
    // The line while be printer even
    // if the condition is false
    document.write("<tr><td>");
    document.write(x);
    document.write("</td>");

    document.write("<td>");
    document.write("FAILED");
    document.write("</td>");
  } else {
    document.write("<tr><td>");
    document.write(x);
    document.write("</td>");

    document.write("<td>");
    document.write("PASSED");
    document.write("</td>");
  }
```

So in here I need it to be Color red when failed and green when passed but I know how too change font color but I don't know it when it's in table and need to be if-else statement? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Set the color via a style attribute:
`style="color:red"` or `style="color:green"` on the `<tr>`

like this:

```
var x = 65;

do {
  if (x >= 75) {
    // The line while be printer even
    // if the condition is false
    document.write("<tr style='color=red'><td>");
    document.write(x);
    document.write("</td>");

    document.write("<td>");
    document.write("FAILED");
    document.write("</td>");
  } else {
    document.write("<tr style='color=green'><td>");
    document.write(x);
    document.write("</td>");

    document.write("<td>");
    document.write("PASSED");
    document.write("</td>");
  }
```

Of course you could / should do this not via inline-styles but put the definitions in css classes and then put the class on the rows.

Comment: I tried       'document.write("<tr><td>");
            document.write(x);
                document.write("</td>");
               
                document.write("<td style="color:red">");
            document.write("PASSED");
                document.write("</td>");'
But it doesn't work

Comment: I adapted my code, you probably messed up nesting of "", check out my code now, it should work.. @JONKIM

Answer (score 0):

```
#red {
  color:red;
}
#green {
  color:green;
}

document.write('<p id="red">FAILED</p>')
document.write('<p id="green">PASSED</p>')
```